# How To Write Student object To A File In C#

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace WriteStudents
{
    class Student
    {
        public String name;
        public int mark;

        public Student(String n, int m)
        {
            name = n;
            mark = m;
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return name + " " + mark;
        }
        void print(Student[] group)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < group.Length; i++)
                Console.WriteLine(group[i]);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String filePath = @"C:\Users\Path\students.txt";
            String[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

            Student[] group = new Student[lines.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            {
                String[] tokens = lines[i].Split(); //split the names from the marks;
                group[i] = new Student(tokens[0], int.Parse(tokens[1]));
            }

            File.WriteAllLines(filePath, group); //error is here

        }
    }
}
```

In this exercise, you read in a set of students from a file. Then you increase each student's mark by 1 and write out the results out to another file. The format of the file will be the same as in the previous exercise. The name of the input file will be the first argument and the name of the output file will be the second argument.

For example, if the input file was:

```
John 50
Abby 40
```

Your program will create the following file:

```
John 51
Abby 41
```

Guys How would I be able to write my Student object to a file? It isn't letting me convert the Student object to a String object. Any ideas?

Comment: google for `serialization in C#`. There are quite a few options available.

Comment: `group.Select( s => $"{s.name} {s.mark}" )` with `import System.Linq` at the top of your program

Comment: If you can `Split` the string into tokens, have you tried using `Join` to combine them again?

Comment: about that `toString` method you wrote: there's already a `ToString` method on every object. it's virtual, you can override it on your `Student` class. `public override string ToString() { return name + " " + mark; }` [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method)

Comment: also, you should not have a `print` method in a data class. see S of [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design))

Comment: That worked, thanks. Also what does Select do? As you can tell I'm new to c#. @Icepickle

Comment: This is literally asking us to write you code. That isn’t what we do, but we’ll tell you what you’re doing wrong.

Comment: I already got the answer I need. I never asked anyone to write code. @StanStrum

Comment: @blazing It sure seems like it: `Your program will create the following file`. This seems like something I’d see on PPCG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method [File.WriteAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3det53xh(v=vs.110).aspx) only takes string[] as the data to output. You are passing an array of your `Student` object.

You need to take the string presentation of the your object, pass that to the write function.

This is just one of many ways to do this:

```
static void SaveAllStudentsToFile(string fileName, Student[] group)
{
    // create a place to hold data
    string[] data = new string[group.Length];

    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < group.Length; i++)
    {
        data[i] = group[i].ToString();
    }

    // now write the data to a file
    File.WriteAllLines(fileName, data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much @BlackFrog